# generic dependency properties is it even possible

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have 2 dependency properties in my code that are typed to 2 different tables in my dbml.

I'd like to make 1 generic dependency property that could handle both tables.  I'm not even sure where to begin.

Is it possible I guess is the first question and if so, are there any good examples on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes you can, if both tables is inheriting the same BaseClass then you can make your dependency property to be the typeof(BaseClass)

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Even if there is no such base class, it would still be possible with property type `System.Object`, which is the ultimate base class of all types in .NET. `FrameworkElement.DataContext` is an example of such a property.

Comment: @Clemens That's true, but not when he has a custom dependency property that has a custom logic that doesn't depend on the built in classes. You know what I mean?